# Phase delay compensation IIR Filter Matlab 2012

Tags: matlab, filter

I designed the following filter and would like to find the zero phase delay between input[x] and filtered signal[Filtsig].  I know how to use y = filtfilt(d,x) but my matlab only suppports the following case only:    Case1 Filtsig=filtfilt(sos,g,x)
    Case2 Filtsig=filtfilt(b,a,x)

```
function Hd = untitled0
%UNTITLED0 Returns a discrete-time filter object.

% MATLAB Code
% Generated by MATLAB(R) 9.0 and the Signal Processing Toolbox 7.2.
% Generated on: 02-Apr-2019 20:28:37

% Butterworth Lowpass filter designed using FDESIGN.LOWPASS.

% All frequency values are in Hz.

Fs = 350;  % Sampling Frequency

Fpass = 60;          % Passband Frequency
Fstop = 70;          % Stopband Frequency
Apass = 1;           % Passband Ripple (dB)
Astop = 80;          % Stopband Attenuation (dB)
match = 'stopband';  % Band to match exactly

% Construct an FDESIGN object and call its BUTTER method.
h  = fdesign.lowpass(Fpass, Fstop, Apass, Astop, Fs);
Hd = design(h, 'butter', 'MatchExactly', match);

Filtsig=filtfilt(sos,g,x)
Filtsig=filtfilt(b,a,x)


% Construct an FDESIGN object and call its BUTTER method.
h  = fdesign.lowpass(Fpass, Fstop, Apass, Astop, Fs);
Hd = design(h, 'butter', 'MatchExactly', match);

Filtsig=filtfilt(sos,g,x)
Filtsig=filtfilt(b,a,x)
```

Comment: Inspecting your object  `Hd` you will see that it includes the sos-Matrix and the scale values. So there is everything you need.

Comment: can you explain in code?